# A question about duplicating Drupal installation on another server

Tags: php, drupal, web-applications, content-management-system

I have hired a programmer overseas to develop a Drupal website for me and he has done a very good job (the site is installed at his server). I payed him and he sent me the Drupal files and the database .sql file.

Here is what I have done so far:

1- I have created a database on my server named something different from the database file he has sent me and imported the .sql file with no problem. (naming the database as the one he has used during development is not possible for me)

2- I have uploaded the Drupal files to the root of my domain.

3- I have modified drupal/site/default/settings.php and put my database information there and I have modified the $base_url variable there.

The problem is that when I access the website I get a white screen and nothing else (even when I click on show source on my browser, it is empty).

I tried to do the same on a localhost on both Mac and Windows using MAMP and WAMP respectively, and I got the same result (empty screen)

anybody has any suggestion about what seems to be the problem?

Best Regards,

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file somewhere? It should be there but may be hidden or forgotten since it can is "hidden" on some OS. Can you access the site via index.php?

Comment: Yeah, I made sure the .htaccess is there and tried to access it via index.php but that did not work. However, I have solved the problem by adding the following line to the settings.php file:

ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anybody has the same issue. Problem has been solved by adding the following line to the PHP settings.php file:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
```

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Its a PHP WSOD error most likely. Do you have a way to check crash logs?

Comment: I have looked at the php error log in wampserver but found nothing related to the problem. I have emptied the log file and tried to access the website again (through localhost), but still nothing shows up in the error log. The same thing when I restarted my wamp server

Comment: Check Apache's error log as well. There's multiple places logs (global httpd.conf, site-specific .conf file, php.ini) can be configured.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [The White Screen of Death](http://drupal.org/node/158043)? Typically when faced with this issue and unable to quickly find the cause I return to this handbook page to go through the possible causes. Unfortunately this is a common symptom of many different problems and can be difficult to pin down.

Comment: Thank you for your help. it is a very interesting line that you gave. However I have solved the problem. Refer to the comments under my question for the solution.